# How can I implement server-side rate limiting for a Perl web service?

Tags: perl, cgi, throttling

I have a Perl-based CGI/Fast CGI web service and want to rate-limit clients by IP address to stop aggressive clients causing too much work.

I have looked around for some code and found [Algorithm::TokenBucket](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-TokenBucket) in CPAN but that is for client requests; it has no persistence and has no per-user config so is not really useful for server-side rate limiting.

I am looking for suggestions for something that already exists, otherwise I'll need to roll my own based on some simple persistence such as tie to [DB_File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DB_File) per-IP address and some batch job that does the token management.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [Cache::FastMmap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cache::FastMmap) for rate-limiting by tracking hits per IP address. It's a cache so data will expire over time, but if you set the size and expire time right, this shouldn't be an issue.

The IP address is the hash key and the hash value is an array of timestamps. I have a second data structure (also backed by [Cache::FastMMap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cache::FastMmap)) which is a hash of banned IP addresses, updated according to the data from the first structure.

Comment: I have had Cache::FastMmap expire entries way before their expiration time, and way before the cache is full (it is all about pages).  With that in mind, I would use BDB instead, and manually expire stale records.

Comment: Well, I've decided on Cache::FastMmap for performance and concurrent access reasons and because *strict* rate-limiting was not required. The latter seems to apply here, I don't know about the former.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not what you asked, but have you considered handling this elsewhere in the stack where it's already been done for you?  Clearly I don't know your deployment stack, but if it's apache you could use [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/projects/mod_evasive/).  Alternately if you're on Linux you could let iptables do its job using something like:

```
#Allow only 12 connections per IP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conn-limit --connlimit-above 12 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

certainly more complicated rules are possible.

Comment: I don't have access to the server config - it's shared hosting so I need the application level to deal with it, in this case perl since that's what I wrote it in.

Comment: I'm looking at rate-limit options for my fastCGI API. I thought mod_evasive was the ideal solution however i've found issue with the module in regards to script requests (non-browser). It seems mod_evasive works on a per second basis, but does not activly work within the second. I.e, you can go over the DOSPageInterval & DOSSiteInterval request limit, if done fast enough. For these reasons i'm looking for alternative solutions. Just a note to anyone looking curiously to mod_evasive